# Can't run my script because Powershell read "-" as â€“

Tags: powershell

This is what I'm trying to run

> Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | where-object {$_.name –notlike "*store*"} | Remove-AppxPackage 2>&1 | Out-Null

And this is the error message I keep getting

> At C:\Users\JKaw\Desktop\AfterFormat\Win10Tweaks.ps1:262 char:51
>   + ... ct {$_.name â€“notlike "*store*"} | Remove-AppxPackage 2>&1 | Out-Nul ...

–notlike > â€“notlike

Is there any workaround for this? I looked for a bit but didn't find any solution!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't copy commands off websites into a console. Retype them.

You have copied the command, including the dash character which a website turned into a fancy Unicode dash just because it could (I'm looking at you, Wordpress), into a non-Unicode-aware console.

This causes the UTF-8-encoded bytes that make up the character to be interpreted as ANSI (in whatever codepage).

Answer (score 5):

You're using the wrong character. 
You currently have an `–` (en-dash, ASCII code 8211). Instead, you should use a regular `-` (hyphen, ASCII code 45):

```
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | where-object {$_.name -notlike "store"} | Remove-AppxPackage 2>&1 | Out-Null
# Here -------------------------------------------^
```

Comment: Yup, that was it. Thank you!