# ConvertFrom−Json : The term 'ConvertFrom−Json' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, azure-ad-graph-api, graph-explorer

I'm running this fairly easy PowerShell command:

`az graph query -q "project id, type, location | where type =~ 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines' | summarize count() by location | top 3 by count_"`

So far so good:

```
{
  "count": 3,
  "data": [
    {
      "count_": 90,
      "location": "westeurope"
    },
    {
      "count_": 41,
      "location": "eastus"
    },
    {
      "count_": 11,
      "location": "germanywestcentral"
    }
  ],
  "skip_token": null,
  "total_records": 3
}
```

I want to format the JSON to something more readable so I will use the [ConvertFrom-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7.3) option:

`az graph query -q "project id, type, location | where type =~ 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines' | summarize count() by location | top 3 by count_"  | ConvertFrom-Json`

but this results in:

```
ConvertFrom−Json : The term 'ConvertFrom−Json' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At line:1 char:153
+ ...  summarize count() by location | top 3 by count_"  | ConvertFrom−Json
+                                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ConvertFrom−Json:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Why and how to install ConvertFrom−Json?

shouldn't be there by default?

Comment: I tried it on my PC, I'm not a PS enthusiast, so it's pretty vanilla. I can run `ConvertFrom-Json` without a problem.

Comment: Could it be that you have some old PS? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22256706/running-powershell-script-in-c-sharp-converttojson-error) it's mentioned it should be 3.0+, mine is 5.1.1

Comment: Duplicate: [Can't run my script because Powershell read "-" as â€“](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41447011/1701026)? "*Don't copy commands off websites into a console. Retype them.*"