# Why Does PowerShell Give a False Alarm About Approved Verbs?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I rebooted my machine, and tried running the debugger again. Still fails to launch. Here's what I got.

WARNING: The names of some imported commands from the module 'TchPublisherArguments' include unapproved verbs that might make them less discoverable. To find the commands with unapproved verbs, run the Import-Module command again with the Verbose parameter. For a list of approved verbs, type Get-Verb.
Write-Error: The term 'Send-Files' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

```
MyCommand             : 
BoundParameters       : {}
UnboundArguments      : {}
ScriptLineNumber      : 303
OffsetInLine          : 34
HistoryId             : 1
ScriptName            : C:\Users\Dick\Documents\tch\code\scripts\PowerShell\modules\TchPublisherArguments\TchPublisherArguments.psm1       
Line                  :       "send-local-clear"       { Send-Files -target local  -clearArchive $true  ; Confirm-AndExit }

PositionMessage       : At
                        C:\Users\Dick\Documents\tch\code\scripts\PowerShell\modules\TchPublisherArguments\TchPublisherArguments.psm1:303   
                        char:34
                        +       "send-local-clear"       { Send-Files -target local  -clearArch …
                        +                                  ~~~~~~~~~~
PSScriptRoot          : C:\Users\Dick\Documents\tch\code\scripts\PowerShell\modules\TchPublisherArguments
PSCommandPath         : C:\Users\Dick\Documents\tch\code\scripts\PowerShell\modules\TchPublisherArguments\TchPublisherArguments.psm1       
InvocationName        : Send-Files
PipelineLength        : 0
PipelinePosition      : 0
ExpectingInput        : False
CommandOrigin         : Internal
DisplayScriptPosition :
```

Comment: Please provide relevant source of the module so we can try and reproduce the issue.

Comment: E-mail address?

Comment: If you can't publicly share the code, you may add a minimal, reproducible example to the question.

Comment: The hint to solve this was already provided in the comments of your previous question. You're using a custom psd1 with rules to warn the usage of `Send` in your settings.json

Comment: What PowerShell version? Especially on earlier versions, watch out for [en-dashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41446952/cant-run-my-script-because-powershell-read-as-%C3%A2%E2%82%AC) if you copy and past code (just retype the command).

Comment: This looks like it might be two unconnected issues. Have you tried (i) adding ```-Verbose``` to your call to ```Import-Module``` per the suggestion in the warning? This will tell you the names of the offending commands (ii) running ```Get-Command “Send-Files”``` to confirm there’s actually a command available with that name? I’m pretty sure the warning about verbs is just a warning - it doesn’t actually prevent the offending commands being loaded…

Comment: Yes, I had already run Import-Module -Verbose. It pointed to the same offending code. Interestingly enough, it gave the same warning, that I was using an "unapproved" verb ("Send"). So that means we have two different cmdlets giving different answers to the same question. Import-Module said "Send" was unapproved, but Get-Verb showed it on the "approved". Just guessing here, but perhaps the Poweshell infrastructure has different "approved verb" lists, which were originally the same, but have diverged and now have some differences.But I have functioning code now, I'm fine with closing this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found a workaround, though not a satisfactory answer. I replaced the verb **Send** with the verb **Publish**, and the error disappeared.

The question still remains, though as to why PowerShell complained about **Send**, and not about **Publish**. If I recall correctly, it complained at **Publish** this morning or yesterday, and that's why I changed it to **Send**. But both verbs are approved, so it shouldn't have complained about *either*.

But at least now I can continue to work.

Thanks to all who tried to help!

Comment: Perhaps because Publish is listed as a Data verb, while Send is a Communications verb... though that's just a guess

Answer (score 1):

Not able to reproduce the issue:

[Create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

- Create file named: `.\Send-Files.psm1`
- Add content:

```
function Send-Files {
    param()
    Write-Host 'Sending Files...'
}

Export-ModuleMember -Function Send-Files
```

- Import the module: `Import-Module .\Send-Files.psm1`
  (No warnings received)

As an aside, [the PowerShell team best practices state cmdlets should use singular nouns and not plurals](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/utility-modules/psscriptanalyzer/rules/usesingularnouns).
In other words it is recommended to use the cmdlet name: `Send-File` instead. Knowing that if your cmdlet correctly [supports Input from the Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/strongly-encouraged-development-guidelines#support-the-processrecord-method), it should send each **file** one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Does `Send-Files` exist within your `TchPublisherArguments` module, and if so, is your code running successfully but just showing that warning each time?

If so then the warning simply relates to the fact that you're using a verb, eg `Send`, that isn't approved for use within PowerShell by Microsoft, as for consistency across scripts they recommend using consistent verbs.

It it just a warning, so you can optionally override it so the warning no longer shows up by calling the module with

```
Import-Module TchPublisherArguments -disablenamechecking
```

You can see a list of the approved verbs and their usage here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands?view=powershell-7.3

though I notice `Send` is on the list, but it's listed under Communications Verbs, so in this case it may also be because you're using it unintended purposes, rather than perhaps `Copy-` or `Move-` for transferring a file/resource from one place to another, which in the contact of files is what I'd guess you're doing.